# Android In-app product that is not consumable, but several can be purchased

Tags: android, google-play, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing

I am having confusion choosing a suitable **product type** of a commodity in my utility android application.

My application is of a kind where the user is benefitted through the number of **'slots'** that they own. Think of it like the length of a ListView. My free application will feature a maximum length of that ListView upto 5. But if a user needs more List Items, they can buy subsequent List Item slots. The user should be able to buy as many as they like at 0.50$ each.

The problem is that, my in-app product neither comes under the definition of a 'managed product' alone, nor does it come under the definition of a 'consumable product' alone. I need the 'slot' product able to be purchased as many times as the user likes. But at same time, i also want Google Play to keep track of the ownership of the amount of slots per user.

As the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/api.html#producttypes) (and several tutorials out there) suggest:

- If i want Google Play to ***store the purchase information for each item on a per-user basis***, i will have to declare my product as a managed (non-consumable) product.
- If i want my product able to be purchased many times, i would have to  ***implement consumption for items that can be purchased multiple times***.

The predicament is that i want both the features.

One bad solution is that I feature several slot products as unique products (alpha slot, beta slot, ... and so on), and then treat them as the same thing. However, i'd like to know of a solution that's more correct and sensible.

Another solution could be to make use of a separate cloud service to keep track of the number of slots bought by users, but i don't want that. That would be overkill. Also, i'd like to make use of the 'local caching' feature of Google Play Store.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I asked Google Play Developer Support if there were any way that Google Play Store could keep count of consumable in-app products. Turns out, at the moment, it is not possible.

Here is the actual reply (Nov 3, 2016):

---

*I wanted to know whether Play Store also keeps record of the count of a 
CONSUMABLE in-app item that a user has bought even after the user 
uninstalls and then reinstalls the app? 
In short, after user reinstalls, is there any way of knowing as to how many 
of a single in-app item has the user ever bought?*

> Hi,
>
> Thanks for contacting Google Play Developer Support.
>
> I checked into it and the Play Developer Console doesn’t currently
>   support tracking every individual users every IAP purchase for
>   developers to see. Luckily, we place a high value on developer
>   feedback, and I’ll be sure to pass along your specific feedback to our
>   product team. We’re continually adding new features and functionality,
>   so please stay tuned.
>
> You can always check the Android Developers Blog for any new features
>   and updates: http://android-developers.blogspot.com/

Comment: Yeah, I'd say you just want a whole heap of products called `slot0`, `slot1`, `slot2`, etc. It's all strings in the API, and you can use a common pricing template in the developer console, so it's not that bad. Surely your app must have some number of slots above which there is no benefit? 1000?

Comment: I did exactly that. Yeah, there is only a sensible number of words that i should allow my users to add for learning, for effectiveness.

Comment: @Karu currently I am offering 10 slots. You can check out my app www.odnvt.com