# Keep count of consumable in-app purchases using Firebase Realtime Database

Tags: android, firebase, in-app-purchase, firebase-realtime-database, in-app-billing

My android app features **'slots'**

- Many can be bought (should be non-consumable in-app purchase)
- I must still keep track of how many slots the user owns (should be consumable in-app purchase)
- I don't want to incorporate user sign-up/sign-in requirement
- I want the count of slots to be immediately available to my app (local caching feature of play store)

This was the predicament that I have been into as I have asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38967014/android-in-app-product-that-is-not-consumable-but-several-can-be-purchased)

**My Solution (so far):**
The solution that I had decided up til now was that I will make several finite non-consumable items (like first-slot, second-slot ... etc). It's not the best solution.

Just recently I came to know about [Firebase Realtime Database](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/start/). I wanted to ask the experts if I could use Firebase Realtime Database for storing the slot counts the way I want, reliably, and without having the users to ever need to sign-up? I might be able to cater for the immediate and reliable retrieval of my data by using the `setPersistenceEnabled (boolean isEnabled)` of my Firebase database instance, as documented [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/FirebaseDatabase.html#setPersistenceEnabled(boolean))

I just wanted to be sure, before I moved ahead, whether I am on the right path?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I contacted Firebase Support and it turns out that i **CANNOT** do that without implementing some sort of Account keeping per user.

Here is the actual reply:

---

*I have been meaning to store count of a consumable in-app item for every user persistently.
Google play does not allow me to do that unless it is a non-consumable. I wanted to know if using firebase real-time database automatically keeps the data linked to the android users' google account?*

> Currently, there's no behavior of automatically handling the user
>   information or custom data associated with Google account when using
>   Firebase Realtime Database. You have to create your data linking
>   module associated with the user Google accounts and attach it with the
>   associated Firebase Realtime Database node of the user.

*Is the data stored in the realtime database automatically per every user? If the user uninstall and then reinstalls, will the data remain?*

> You need to create your module in handling the data of the user using
>   Firebase Realtime Database or with your Server API. Note: Firebase
>   Realtime Database persistence/cache will be removed once the app is
>   uninstalled.