# Retrieve How Many times a same Manged Product is Purchased and Consumed

Tags: android, in-app-purchase

My App has a paid task and to do that task user has to purchase a product.They have to purchase the same product every time when they need to do that task.In this scenario, I need to know how many times the product is brought.How to achieve this.

Comment: I am just using a Preference to store the count, whenever user purchases the product.But once the app is uninstalled and installed the value is lost.I could not store the same in the server, hence I don't want it to be tied with UserId.I need to retrieve from Google Play Store. I need to know if its possible to do so.

Comment: I got my answer from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38967014/android-in-app-product-that-is-not-consumable-but-several-can-be-purchased?rq=1